# Git - finding a git repository on Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am trying to find a git repository on my VM running Ubuntu. I assume it has been created, but not sure. What is the best way to find out if any git repository is present? I have installed git.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I view all the git repositories on my machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020812/how-can-i-view-all-the-git-repositories-on-my-machine)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to search your entire system for a git repo, then I would advise using **find**.

Every git repo has a **.git** folder, so by using find to search for them, you could return every directory that contains a **.git** folder.

```
$ find ~ -type d -name ".git" -print
```

This will output all folders that are git repositories within your user account.

Otherwise if you want to check if the directory you are in is already a git repo, you would simply run:

```
$ git status
```

It will return either

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

or

```
On branch master
```

Answer (score 0):

On the topmost level directory of your repo, you can try:

```
 $ cd .git
```

If it is not failing, then certainly that is a git repository.

Every git repository has a `.git` hidden directory at its topmost level.

Hope it helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

On the directory you assume that is a repository, try following command:

```
$ git status
```

If this directory contains a repository, it will show something like this:

```
On branch master
```