# How to find all the .git without permission denied message?

Tags: git, ubuntu, grep, find, permission-denied

(I have Ubuntu)
I have some git repositories here and there on my computer. So I want to have the status of all in one command. I found this answer [How can I view all the git repositories on my machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020812/how-can-i-view-all-the-git-repositories-on-my-machine) (@jmlane : for d in `find / -name ".git"`; do cd $d/..; echo `pwd`:; git status; echo; done )

But I have a lot of "Permission denied" messages. So I searched and found this answer [How can I exclude all "permission denied" messages from "find"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762348/how-can-i-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages-from-find) but I don't know how to addapt it to my problem.

I tried `find -name ".git" | grep -v "Permission non accordée"` but I have the same result as just `find -name ".git"` :

```
find: «./.cache/dconf»: Permission non accordée
find: «./.dbus»: Permission non accordée
./Documents/these/programmes/programme_ccm/.git
./Documents/these/rapports/centralisation/.git
./Documents/these/rapports/Barberis_review_2016/.git
./Documents/these/rapports/biblio/.git
```

I tried `find -name ".git" 2> grep -v "Permission non accordée"` with no result

But when I tried `find -name ".git" | grep  "Permission non accordée"` I obtain

```
find: «./.cache/dconf»: Permission non accordée
find: «./.dbus»: Permission non accordée
```

Comment: have you tried to use your commands with su/sudo to launch it with admin rights?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762348/how-can-i-exclude-all-permission-denied-messages-from-find

Comment: @vmchar I tried right now : doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked fine on my machine:

```
find -name ".git" 2> /dev/null
```

It puts error-stream to the special file /dev/null, which is simpy voidness.

your code:

```
find -name ".git" 2> grep -v "Permission non accordee"
```

was about to redirect error output to file named grep in your working directory.

Comment: and btw it sets -v as a flag of find, and so then find doesn't know this flag, and returns error code and error output 'Unknown flag'.

Comment: Ok so I didn't understand this command ^^ 
So the 2> is to redirect the errors. And what I want to derirect just the `Permission denied`errors and not others ? 
Why the pipe | didn't work ?

Comment: Because pipe takes standart output to grep, so the error output is being displayed manually. find -name ".git" 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permission denied' In case with pipe, on my machine it first prints about permission denied, and then -- the others, filtered by grep, which is logical. First find makes it's job and finds everything(and prints errors, since errorstream is not redirected), and then it redirects it's std output as input for grep, but it already doesn't contain errors. In line I give here -- we run find and redirect errorstream to std(2>&1) and it works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `locate` package installed and `updatedb` is being run from `cron`? If yes, `locate` is you friend. The command

```
locate -b \*.git
```

will be much faster than `find`. Also `locate` takes permissions into account automatically — the output will list only `.git` and `*.git` repositories that are accessible by the current user.

Comment: I have `locate` and `man updatedb` gave me the documentation so I suppose I have it too. I don't know for `cron`.
The command you gave doesn't give me the same result : I have a `/oracle.jdeveloper.git` file and I don't want to have it but the worst is that I have only one /.git instead of 5