# VSCode: No extensions found. However the ~/.vscode/extensions folder has all the extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

**I'm an idiot + Solution:**

What was happening was that the folders all remained (within the extensions folder) but the files were all discarded. This made it appear like the extensions were there but really it was just their folders / subfolders.

I went through and manually reinstalled them and they populated their respective folders with the files.

I have no idea what I discarded. Everything else seems to be working fine.

Edit1: I am using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020812/how-can-i-view-all-the-git-repositories-on-my-machine) to search through my drive for all git repos. I have no idea how one ended up there but I want to make sure this doesn't happen in the future.

Edit2: Here are the culprits:

```
/Users/Home/.git
/Users/Home/.oh-my-zsh/.git
```

Edit3: the .oh-my-zsh git repo is valid. the issue was with `/Users/Home/.git`. Removed the latter.

----- Original Question below

I am confused on what happened here. Last night I switched to a new project and suddenly the Git integration in VSC went wild. It had something like 10,000 changes it asked me to stage. I discarded all the changes and went about my way.

Two things happened at this point:

OhMyZSH broke. I had to uninstall / reinstall to get it working again.

VSCode broke. None of my extensions are here anymore. Any new extensions I tried to add are in the extensions folder but are not being recognized by VSC. I havent seen an option to set / reset the extensions folder filepath anywhere.

Has this happened to anyone else? Can you help me sort this out?

Comment: Side question: what can I do to prevent the 10,000 changes showing up? This seems to happen sporadically. Sometimes it shows up when I open a new project other times it doesnt. In the past I just discarded the changes and everything was fine. This time it broke.

Comment: Pretty important detail is, what were the changes you discarded? Maybe you have a git repo in your home folder, and you discarded extension files?

Comment: I think thats exactly what happened. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

What was happening was that the folders all remained (within the extensions folder) but the files were all discarded. This made it appear like the extensions were there but really it was just their folders / subfolders.

I went through and manually reinstalled them and they populated their respective folders with the files.

I have no idea what I discarded. Everything else seems to be working fine.

Edit1: I am using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020812/how-can-i-view-all-the-git-repositories-on-my-machine) to search through my drive for all git repos. I have no idea how one ended up there but I want to make sure this doesn't happen in the future.

Edit2: Here are the culprits:

```
/Users/Home/.git
/Users/Home/.oh-my-zsh/.git
```

Edit3: the .oh-my-zsh git repo is valid. the issue was with `/Users/Home/.git`. Removed the latter.

Answer (score 0):

@vampiire
I've found that quitting VSC, restarting my computer, and reopening VSC solves 99% of the 5,000+ changes issues.

Also found out - the hard way - to be sure and keep repos within the GitHub Folder in my Documents Folder.  When they branch out to the Documents folder, VSC thinks every change made in my Documents folder should now be included ...