# Navigating to GitHub repository on command line

Tags: github

I've created a GitHub repository through the command line, but can't figure out how to navigate back to it. Is there a command that can show me all the repositories on my computer, and go to it?

I'm using Windows 10

Edit: not duplicate, all the answers relevant to windows are outdated and don't work, and others concern linux.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Updated question - thanks for reminder!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I view all the git repositories on my machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020812/how-can-i-view-all-the-git-repositories-on-my-machine)