# Looking for folders containing bare git repositories

Tags: git

If they were working copy of git repositories, we could start simply with the approach of looking for every folder with the name ".git" (`find . -type d -name ".git"`), as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020812/how-can-i-view-all-the-git-repositories-on-my-machine).

But in big storages, how to detect all folders containing **bare git repositories**?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46758507/1290731

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code:

```
locate -b \*.git |
    while read path; do
        if [ -f "$path" ]; then
            echo "$path is a gitlink file (perhaps in a submodule)"
        elif [ -d "$path" ]; then
            if [ "`basename \"$path\"`" = .git ]; then
                echo "$path is repository"
            else
                echo "$path is bare repo"
            fi
        fi
    done
```

Warning 1: To use `locate` you need your system to be configured to run `updatedb` regularly (usually nightly from `cron`)

Warning 2: The code supposes all your bare repositories are named `name.git`. Mine are.

Comment: This doesn't find bare repositories, but regular ones.

Comment: Works for me. `name/.git` are regular repositories, `name.git` are bare ones.

Comment: That's the problem, they might have lots of different names not following the convention `name.git`

Comment: Conventions are to make things convenient. Those who don't follow them punish themselves unnecessary. Well, then testing for the content like in the linked duplicate is the only solution.