# Looking for folders containing valid git bare repositories

Tags: git

In big storages, how to detect all folders containing only **bare git repositories**?

I don't mean just looking for the usual content or some content of git bare repositories, but real valid repositories.

**CURRENT APPROACH:**

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46758507/926064) just find folders having basic content that may look like a git bare repository, so we could improve it trying to execute `git status` on every folder matching this basic structure, but I'm not sure it would be the best approach to ensure this is a bare repository, not to say that git status returns the error `fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree` on bare repositories requiring us to assume it means a bare repository. So we would have to expect to receive that output for each checking and only thus assume it's a valid git bare repository.

Is there any better way to find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should detect them the way Git detects them, which is outlined in the answer you quoted.  To wit, you need the following:

- an `objects/` directory;
- a `refs/` directory; and
- either a `HEAD` symlink or a `HEAD` file that is properly formatted.

The exact specification is documented in the source code in `setup.c`.

If you have what you suspect is a Git repository, you can change into it and run `git rev-parse --git-dir`, which will exit successfully if you're in a Git repository, and exit unsuccessfully if you're not.  You can also use `git rev-parse --is-bare-repository` and look for either `true` or `false` to determine whether your repository is bare.

If you don't want to change into the repository, you can use `git -C <DIR> rev-parse --git-dir` and similar to operate on the mentioned directory instead.

Comment: Thanks about `git rev-parse --is-bare` and `git rev-parse --git-dir`