# How to run command on all git repositories on a machine?

Tags: bash, git, shell, loops

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020812/how-can-i-view-all-the-git-repositories-on-my-machine) I came up with this command to find out all `.git` repositories on my machine.

`find / -type d -name .git 2>&-`

And it works relatively fast. Though I hear my CPU's fan a little, which shows that my machine does some work.

Now I want to be able to loop over the results and run git commands on each of them. For example, I want to get their status to see what should be managed.

I tried:

`find / -type d -name .git 2>&- | xargs git status`

But it didn't work:

> fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

I also tried:

`find / -type d -name .git 2>&- | xargs dirname | xargs git status`

Again, the same error.

What command should I use?

Comment: You need to write a script that can differentiate bare and non bare repos and run the appropriate command in the right directory

Comment: Instead of using xargs, you can pass -exec to find

Comment: @MadPhysicist, that's not important to me. My loop doesn't work.

Comment: Because you can't run in the git folder of a non bare repo and you can't run in the parent folder of a bare one. Hence the need for a script

Comment: If that's the difference, then I would turn it into a script as you said. But in my case, all are the same (either bare or non-bare I don't know). My current problem is that my loop is not working. I can't loop over them.

Comment: Try my answer to your linked question.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is simply : suppose your cwd is `$HOME`, and your repository is in `$HOME/my/repo`,
`git status $HOME/my/repo` will *not* look for a git repository stored in `my/repo`, it will search for a repository starting from `$HOME` and going upwards (and it probably won't find one).

---

There are several ways to fix this :

- `cd` to target directory before running `git status` :

  ```
  cd <path/to/repo>; git status
  ```
- name the target `.git` repository using `git -C` :

  ```
  git -C <path/to/repo> status
  ```

To combine your `find` command with `xargs` :

- use `dirname` to turn `/path/to/repo/.git` into `/path/to/repo`,
- use `xargs -i` to allow to place the argument somewhere else than "the last position" :

```
find . -name .git | xargs dirname | xargs -i git -C {} status

# or :
find . -name .git | xargs dirname |\
    xargs -i bash -c "echo ===== {}; git -C {} status"
```

Comment: I initially posted an answer saying "only set `GIT_DIR`", but you actually also need to set `GIT_WORK_TREE`. `git -C path/to/repo` is more convenient (it sets "both").

Answer (score 0):

You can also try and use [`dirk-thomas/vcstool`](https://github.com/dirk-thomas/vcstool) (python-based)

> Vcstool is a version control system (VCS) tool, designed to make working with multiple repositories easier.

```
vcs status /path/to/several/repos /path/to/other/repos /path/to/single/repo
```

Other approach (shell-based): [`sascha-andres/devenv`](https://github.com/sascha-andres/devenv)

> `devenv` is a tool to manage projects containing multiple git repositories. >
> With a config you can setup all repositories with one command and even work with the local repositories as if they where one ( eg creating branches in all referenced projects) using the shell.

Answer (score -1):

I use this:

```
find . \
  -type d \
  -exec sh -c '[ -e "$1/.git" ]' - {} \; \
  -prune \
  -exec git -C {} status \;
```

It:

- isn’t very fast.
- will skip nested repositories (e.g. submodules).
- works with work trees, but not bare repositories.

Here’s an alternative that should work with bare repositories:

```
find . \
  -type d \
  -exec sh -c 'git -C "$1" rev-parse --git-dir >/dev/null 2>&1' - {} \; \
  -prune \
  -exec git -C {} status \;
```